# Call Servlet and invoke Java code from JavaScript along with parameters

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets, parameter-passing

I have session key that is a JavaScript variable which I got from a REST API call. I need to call my Java code in a servlet and pass that key as a parameter. What JavaScript function can I use to do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Several ways:

1. Use `window.location` to fire a GET request. Caveat is that it"s synchronous (so the client will see the current page being changed).

   ```
   window.location = "http://example.com/servlet?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key);
   ```

   Note the importance of built-in `encodeURIComponent()` function to encode the request parameters before passing it.
2. Use `form.submit()` to fire a GET or POST request. The caveat is also that it"s synchronous.

   ```
   document.formname.key.value = key;
   document.formname.submit();
   ```

   With

   ```
   <form name="formname" action="servlet" method="post">
       <input type="hidden" name="key">
   </form>
   ```

   Alternatively you can also only set the hidden field of an existing form and just wait until the user submits it.
3. Use `XMLHttpRequest#send()` to fire an asynchronous request in the background (also known as Ajax). Below example will invoke servlet"s `doGet()`.

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("GET", "http://example.com/servlet?key=" + encodeURIComponent(key));
   xhr.send(null);
   ```

   Below example will invoke servlet"s `doPost()`.

   ```
   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhr.open("POST", "http://example.com/servlet");
   xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhr.send("key=" + encodeURIComponent(key));
   ```
4. Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to send a crossbrowser compatible Ajax request (above `xhr` code works in real browsers only, for MSIE compatibility, you"ll need to add some clutter ;) ).

   ```
   $.get("http://example.com/servlet", { "key": key });
   ```

   ```
   $.post("http://example.com/servlet", { "key": key });
   ```

   Note that jQuery already transparently encodes the request parameters all by itself, so you don"t need `encodeURIComponent()` here.

Either way, the `key` will be just available by `request.getParameter("key")` in the servlet.

#### See also:

- [How to use Servlets and Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax)
- [Access Java / Servlet / JSP / JSTL / EL variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832792/access-java-servlet-jsp-jstl-el-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript function per se, but browsers usually* provide an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object and you can [go through that](http://www.jibbering.com/2002/4/httprequest.html).

[Libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries) such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com) provide helper functions to simplify its usage.

* for a value of "usually" that includes pretty much any browser that supports JavaScript and was released since Netscape 4 died

Answer (score 1):

When sending POST add header
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

The code looks like
**Client:**

```
    function executeRequest(req) {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
               // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
               document.getElementById("response").value = xhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xhttp.open("POST", "execute/cardbrowser", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send("lorem=ipsum&name=binny");
    }
```

**Server:**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(req.getParameter("lorem"));
}
```