# How to get the dynamic values in jquery from jsp?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, jstl

Here is my jsp code

```
<%
String amount = properties.get("./amount","");
String amount1 = properties.get("./amount1","");
for(i=0;i<7;i++){
%>
<div class="className-<%=i%>">
  <div class= first<%i%>>
   <%=amount%>
  </div>
  <div class= second<%i%>>
  <%=amount1%>
</div>
</div>
<%}
%>
```

How can i get the value of amount and amount1 in jquery ?

Comment: What is properties definition?

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832792/access-request-object-in-javascript

Comment: In my tool to get the values i have to use this. the major concern is how to egt the value which is define in class. because class name is also generating dynamically so classname.text() method will also not work ij this case

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
<script>
var amount = <%=amount%>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

e.g:

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++){var amount = $('.first'+i).text(); var amount1 = $('.second'+i).text();}
```

BTW, did you miss the "=" in "<%i%>"?

Answer (score 0):

If I clearly understand your question you can try assigning value of amount to a hidden input and can get easily in jquery.

```
<input type = "hidden" id = "amountId" value = "<%=amount%>">
```

Is that you need let me know.