# Display JSON objects from Java Servlets inside HTML5 table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I am doing a client management system java web application and I trying to display all the category from my DB:Mysql. I created a few class, 1 servlets and 1 html. Could someone kindly teach me how do I display the JSON objects output from the servlets inside the html5 table(html file)?
        Many thanks.

```
    This is the category Object class.

    package dto;
    public class CategoryObjects {
        private String category_id;
        private String category_name;
        private String category_desc;

        public String getCategory_id() {
            return category_id;
        }
        public void setCategory_id(String category_id) {
            this.category_id = category_id;
        }
        public String getCategory_name() {
            return category_name;
        }
        public void setCategory_name(String category_name) {
            this.category_name = category_name;
        }
        public String getCategory_desc() {
            return category_desc;
        }
        public void setCategory_desc(String category_desc) {
            this.category_desc = category_desc;
        }







    }

    this is the data access object where the sql statements
    package dao;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import dto.CategoryObjects;

    public class catProject {

        public ArrayList<CategoryObjects>GetCategory(Connection connection,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception{

            ArrayList<CategoryObjects>categoryData = new ArrayList<CategoryObjects>();
            try{
                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT `category_id`, `category_name`, `category_desc` FROM `category` ORDER BY `category_id` DESC");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    CategoryObjects catObject = new CategoryObjects();
                    catObject.setCategory_id(rs.getString("category_id"));
                    catObject.setCategory_name(rs.getString("category_name"));
                    catObject.setCategory_desc(rs.getString("category_desc"));
                    categoryData.add(catObject);
                }
                return categoryData;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                throw e;
            }
        }

    }

    this is my model package where I validate
    package model;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import dto.CategoryObjects;
    import dao.catProject;
    public class ProjectCategory {


        public ArrayList<CategoryObjects>  GetCategory(Connection connection, HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
            ArrayList<CategoryObjects> category = null;
            try{
                catProject projectcat = new catProject();
                category=projectcat.GetCategory(connection, request, response);

            }catch (Exception e){
                throw e;
            }
            return category;
        }
    }


    this is my servlets
    package controls;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;

    import dao.Database;
    import model.ProjectCategory;
    import dto.CategoryObjects;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class GetCategory
     */
    @WebServlet("/GetCategory")
    public class GetCategory extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public GetCategory() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            try{
                Database database =new Database();
                ProjectCategory projectcategory = new ProjectCategory();
                ArrayList<CategoryObjects> catData = null;
                Connection connection = database.Get_Connection();
                catData = projectcategory.GetCategory(connection,request,response);
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                System.out.println(gson.toJson(catData));
                String category = gson.toJson(catData);
                out.println("{\"Messages\":"+category+"}");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
            out.close();
            }

        }



    }



The servlets is giving this output:
{"Messages":[{"category_id":"3","category_name":"anger management","category_desc":"for people who always get angry"},{"category_id":"2","category_name":"lazy management","category_desc":"for people who are very lazy"},{"category_id":"1","category_name":"Self-development","category_desc":"for people who are very lazy"}]} 

How do I from this out pass the data to my manageCategory.html file where I can store this data in of table??
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>I'MPOSSIBLE - Manage Categories</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="css/home.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!-- tablesorter theme file-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.default.css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- start of navigation bar  -->
    <nav id="navMenu"></nav>
    <!-- End of navigation bar  -->

    <div class="container">


        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <h1>Manage Category</h1>

                    <ul class="breadcrumb">
                        <li><a href="adminIndex.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="manageCategory.html">Manage
                                Category</a></li>
                    </ul>



                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Category List</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">


                    <div class="pull-right">
                        <!--  Icons for delete, edit and copy -->
                        <p class="icons">
                            <a href="addCategory.html"><button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add
                                </button></a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"
                                onclick="confirm('Delete/Uninstall cannot be undone! Are you sure you want to do this?') ? $('#form-product').submit() : false;">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                            </button>
                            <a href="editCategory.html"><button type="button"
                                    class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Edit
                                </button></a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-copy"></span> Copy
                            </button>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                        id="form-category">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table id="myTable"
                                class="table table-bordered table-hover tablesorter">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="width: 1px;" class="text-center"
                                            data-sorter="false"><input type="checkbox"
                                            onclick="$('input[name*=\'selected\']').prop('checked', this.checked);" /></td>

                                        <td class="text-left"><a href="#" class="asc">Category
                                                Name</a></td>

                                        <td class="text-left"><a href="#" class="asc">Category Description</a></td>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="33" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Couples Counselling</td>
    <td class="text-left">For couples</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="25" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Family Counseling</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">For Family</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="29" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Individual Counselling</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">For Individuals</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="28" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Child and Youth Counselling</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">For child and youth</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="35" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Adjustment/Transition Change
                                            Counselling</td>
                                                <td class="text-left">For adjustment</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="text-center"><input type="checkbox"
                                            name="selected[]" value="36" /></td>
                                        <td class="text-left">Grief Counselling</td>
                                            <td class="text-left">For grief</td>

                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">

                            <ul class="pagination">
                                <li class="disabled"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
                            </ul>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">Showing 1 to 20 of 38 (2
                            Pages)</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <!-- <End> -->
    <!-- Start of <Fixed footer> -->
    <!-- end of body container -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-text pull-left">
                <p>&#169;COPYRIGHT 2015 I'MPOSSIBLE</p>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-text pull-right">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x"></i></a> <a
                    href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                    class="fa fa-google-plus fa-2x"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                    class="fa fa-linkedin-square fa-2x"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Start of <Fixed footer> -->
    <footer id="footerMenu"></footer>
    <!-- End of <Fixed footer> -->

    <script src="js/navlinks-admin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/footer.js"></script>

    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script
        src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- load jQuery and tablesorter scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>

    <!-- tablesorter widgets (optional) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"></script>
    <script> 

<!--    Start by telling tablesorter to sort your table when the document is loaded: -->
    $(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter();
});

<!-- pass in configuration options when you initialize the table. This tells tablesorter to sort on the first and second column in ascending order.  -->
$(function(){
  $("#myTable").tablesorter({ sortList: [ [1,0], [2,0],] });
});


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question is a bit long winded, but I think either one of those answers is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/3832792 If so, can you tell which one exactly?

Comment: hi BalusC, the first link you gave was very helpful. I finally solved my error. By using this:

Comment: $(document).ready(function()
  {
 
 
 $.ajax
 ({
 type: "GET",
 url: "GetCategory",
 dataType:"json",
 success: function(data)
 {
 if(data.Messages.length)
 {
  /*  var $table = $("<table>").appendTo($("#myTable"));  */
 $.each(data.Messages, function(i,data)
 {
   var html = "<tr><td>" + data.category_id + "</td><td>" + data.category_name+ "</td><td>"+data.category_desc+"</td></tr>";
      $('#myTable').append(html);