# Printing EL string "RP" in a JavaScript alert() causes JS error "'RP' is undefined"

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl, el

In my servlet I am creating a multi-dimensional array that I am trying to use in my JSP to check something.  Here it is my setup in the servlet:

```
        List<List<String>> tableList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        for (String selectedItem : selectedItems) 
           {
             String schedcombo = selectedItem;
             Integer modifyScheduleNum = Integer.parseInt(schedcombo.substring(0,5));
             Integer modifyContractYear = Integer.parseInt(schedcombo.substring(5,9));

             String newStatus = request.getParameter("ModifyStatus_" + selectedItem);
             String newStatusDate = request.getParameter("ModifyStatusDate_" + selectedItem) ;
             System.out.println("Schedule Number being processed is " + modifyScheduleNum + 
                                " with contract year of " + modifyContractYear +
                                " with modified status of " + newStatus +
                                " with modified Status Date of " + newStatusDate);

             List<String> rowpull = new ArrayList<String>();
             rowpull.add(schedcombo.substring(0,5));
             rowpull.add(schedcombo.substring(5,9)) ;
             rowpull.add(newStatus);
             rowpull.add(newStatusDate);

             tableList.add(rowpull);

             request.setAttribute("preeditList",tableList)  ;  

           }
```

I did a print of the array processed and it looks like this:

**The arraylist of table used that is added to table is : [[43080, 2016, RP, 2016-02-04]]**

On the JSP I am doing a loop of my table and inside the loop I check the ArrayList to see if there are processesd in servlet.  Here is my JSP code:

```
    for(var i=0; i<updateformID.selectedSched.length; i++)
           {

              var checkSchedule = document.getElementById("checkedTable").rows[i + 1].cells[1].innerHTML;
              var checkYear = document.getElementById("checkedTable").rows[i + 1].cells[2].innerHTML;

              alert("CheckSchedule being pulled outside the ForEach is " + checkSchedule) ;

             <c:remove var="cksched"/>
             <c:forEach items="${preeditList}" var="editTable">
                <c:set var="cksched" value="${editTable[0]}" scope="request" />
                alert("schedule number Inside the foreach loop " + <c:out value="${cksched}"/>) ;   
                <c:set var="ckeftyear" value="${editTable[1]}" scope="request" />
                alert("eft contract year Inside the foreach loop " + <c:out value="${ckeftyear}"/>) ;    
                <c:set var="ckstatus" value="${editTable[2]}" scope="request" />
                alert("sched status Inside the foreach loop " + <c:out value="${ckstatus}"/>) ;     
                <c:set var="ckstatusDate" value="${editTable[3]}" scope="request" />  
                <c:if test="${cksched == checkSchedule}">  
                    <c:set var="checkfound" value="YES" scope="request"/>
                </c:if>


               </c:forEach>

               alert ("The checkfound variable after the foreach is " + 
                                       <%= request.getAttribute("checkfound") %> ) ;

         }
```

In doing a debug of the screen, when I get to the alert message on the **ckstatus** field it fails saying that 'RP' is undefined.  The first two are showing up correctly.

Is my problem that when I add to the **rowpull** array that I am not putting it in as a string correctly or a syntax in the alert or the actual processing that is just wrong?

Thanks again

Comment: Related/dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3832792

Answer (score 1):

Given that the third element of your list is the string "RP", the following lines of code:

```
<c:set var="ckstatus" value="${editTable[2]}" scope="request" />
alert("sched status Inside the foreach loop " + <c:out value="${ckstatus}"/>) ;
```

generate the following JavaScript code:

```
alert("sched status Inside the foreach loop " + RP) ;
```

This JavaScript code thus tries displaying the value of a JavaScript variable `RP`. Since you haven't defined such a variable, its value is `undefined`.

My advice, if you really need to access data from JavaScript code, would be to

1. Define proper classes containing fields rather than stuff everything as strings into random elements of a list
2. Serialize these objects as JSON using a JSON marshaller and put that JSON string into a request attribute
3. Simply have

   ```
   var arrayOfObjects = ${theJsonString};
   ```

   in the JSP, in order to initialize a JS variable containing the array of JavaScript objects, that you can then use in the rest of the JS code.

Comment: All I know about JSON is what I learn in the last couple days.  In looking on the web on this, it seems that JSON marshaller creates a XML file. Is that the JSON string you are talking about creating or are you talking about creating a JSON object and then using this "stringify" function?   Thanks

Comment: No, JSON and XML are unrelated formats. A JSON mrshaller, as its name indicates, transforms Java objects to a JSON structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer in a question from 2010.  Here is what it says:

The best solution is to let JSP/JSTL generate a JavaScript object variable which you can later access in the JS code.

```
     var groupMap = {
        <c:forEach items="${configuredGroupMap}" var="groupMap" varStatus="loop">
             "${groupMap.key}": "${groupMap.value}"${!loop.last ? ',' : ''}
       </c:forEach>
       };
```

This will end up like the following in client side (rightclick page and View Source to be sure)

```
  var groupMap = {
     "key1": "value1",
     "key2": "value2",
     "key3": "value3"
    };
```

Finally rewrite checkSelection() as follows:

```
 function checkSelection(group, tvalue) {
     if (groupMap[group] == tvalue) {
       alert("equal");
     }
 }
```

What is confusing me in reading this is what is being passed for "group" in the function.  is that an index number that was done in a for loop to show groupmap[0] or something that passed a "key1" or "value1" value.

I don't have enough reputation points to ask in the thread and besides it is 6 years ago anyway.  Anybody have an idea what is meant in the passing of "group"

Thanks for help.