# Using json from a jsp file in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, return-value

I have two files, `file1.js` and `file2.jsp`. file2.jsp is printing a jsonArray in the following way:

```
List<HashMap<String,String>> orderDetailsList1=  null;
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(orderDetailsList1);
out.println(jsonArray);
```

I want to use this `jsonArray` in `file1.js`. How do I do that?

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832792/access-java-servlet-jsp-jstl-el-variables-in-javascript ?

Comment: @JozefChocholacek I don't think it is the same thing as I'm asking. The javascript is not in the jsp. Both of them are separate files and I can't figure out how to use value from the jsp file in the js file. (Both are different files!)