# How to set value in c:set using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstl

I have use jquery & bootstrap in jsp page. I need to set value c:set tag using jquery/JavaScript. Here is my c:set tag:

```
<c:set var="dialog_uomid_c"  />
```

Here is my JavaScript function I tried but value is not set

```
function setValue(){
  $("#dialog_uomid_c").val("Test");
}
```

Please help me set up value to **dialog_uomid_c** from **function setValue**

Comment: Isn't `<c:>` a preprocessor tag?  If so that happens on the server.  javascript cannot access that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Java / Servlet / JSP / JSTL / EL variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832792/access-java-servlet-jsp-jstl-el-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602195/select-option-not-selected-in-the-cchoose-in-bootstap) is based on the same misconception. JSTL / EL is processed on the server side, JavaScript on the client side. So you can only use the server side code to generate / render JavaScript. You cannot use JavaScript to manipulate what already has happened on the server side. If you need JS at the server side you need to do a new (Ajax) request.