# java servlet : run a method in server when webpage finish onload

Tags: java, servlets

i want to run a method in servlet  when client finished onload webpage without need to rewrite or reload the current webpage.i try to use javascript onload event, but need to rewrite back the current page.

how to know a request come from web browser beside using user agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what you mean with *"but need to rewrite back the current page"*, but to the point, you can just use `XMLHttpRequest` (Ajax) to send a HTTP request at an arbitrary moment in JavaScript.

Here's a kickoff example which utilizes [jQuery](http://jquery.com) so that the crossbrowsercompatible boilerplate Ajax code is minimized by a factor over 10 times, just drop it somewhere in the `<head>` of your JSP/HTML document:

```xml
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get('servletURL', function() {
            // Write here some callback function if necessary.
        });
    });
</script>
```

It will invoke the `doGet()` method of a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) mapped on `/servletURL`.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/servletURL"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do your job here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke a javascript function on load and [make a ajax call to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132242/need-to-call-servlet-from-javascript-along-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) with [jQuery](http://www.coderanch.com/t/121919/HTML-JavaScript/Ajax-jQuery-servlets)