# Calling a servlet from a JavaScript with request parameters

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets

I am calling a servlet from JavaScript with request parameters but the servlet is not getting called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <table border="1" cellpadding = "15">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td></tr>
  </body>
</table>
<script>
$('td').click(function(){
    var colIndex = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
    var rowIndex = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    alert('Row: ' + rowIndex + ', Column: ' + colIndex);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/TestFinalWebApp/MyServlet?rowIndex=' + rowIndex + "&colIndex=" + colIndex, true);
    xhr.send(null);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the deployment descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>GetParameters</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.web.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>GetParameters</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

> EDIT:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String rowIndex = request.getParameter("rowIndex");
        String colIndex = request.getParameter("colIndex");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("rowIndex:" + rowIndex + "  colIndex:" + colIndex);
    }
```

Can you please tell me why the servlet is not getting called?

Comment: Where is the code of receiving response from servlet?

Comment: Is the JavaScript function even called? Is the alert shown?

Comment: @alexis - yes the alert is shown..

Comment: @ravi - i will post the code.. let me edit the question

Comment: Are there any errors shown when the JavaScript is executed - i suspect the problem is your doing cross domain request ...

Comment: @digvijay and how do you know the servlet is not called? can you see what the result of the call is in firebug? have you added some logs serverside?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `onLoad` event handler? BTW, you already include jQuery, why don't you use it?

Comment: @digvijay : my friend the ajax code which you have written is incomplete , take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: @digvijay : your servlet code is correct , it seems you have incomplete knowledge of ajax(evenHandler , retrieving response from servlet).

Comment: for people looking to explore more options:


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132242/need-to-call-servlet-from-javascript-along-with-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some comments:

1. Since you already include jQuery, use the [ajax() function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). It has much better error handling and solves many corner cases for you.
2. Update to a more recent version of jQuery. [The latest release is 1.7.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery).
3. `localhost` will only work if the server is on the same machine as the browser. OK during development but will break when you deploy. Either get rid of it (then the browser will prepend it for you) or make sure the URL is generated from the servlet context.

Comment: thanks aaron.. ajax function worked.. I am a newbie so took some time... but got what i required..